# Auto-size the left and the right divs in a three-div layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a bar which has three divs laid out horizontally (floats to left and right). Now, I'd like the middle one to have a fixed size while the left and right divs would automatically fill the rest of the space equally.

In crude ASCII, it'd be something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|      LEFT       | MID |      RIGHT      |
-------------------------------------------
    AUTO-WIDTH     80px      AUTO-WIDTH
```

How do I do this in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with FLEX-model

It's pretty easy to use and works like a charm.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid1">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="grid2">
        Text<br />
        lorem ipsum dolor sit<br />
        text text
    </div>
    <div class="grid1">
        Text
    </div>
</div>

.container { display: flex; }
.container .grid1 { background-color: yellow; flex: 1; }
.container .grid2 { background-color: lime; width: 80px; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/s8pzayep/19/

UPDATED

Comment: this doesn't work with a fixed width for only 1 element.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question directly, but I found a solution by googling this flex thingy. I'll accept your answer if you fix it to reflect my exact question.

Comment: ups, wrong version:
http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/s8pzayep/19/
this is the right one, sorry

And I have updated my solution as well

Comment: it is worth noting Fexbox [is only fully supported from IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)...

Answer (score -1):

Following is what you want. Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`.

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

div{
    border:1px solid;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 150px;
}

.right {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Fixed width
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/s8pzayep/18/)

Comment: I've upvoted the solution, cause it's not wrong at all. No need for a downvote